# WPF - How to make RadioButtons generated by a DataTemplate be mutually exclusive?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, radio-button, datatemplate

One of the apps I am building needs to build a survey for users to take. The relevant classes related to my question are:

```
 Survey (string Description, List<Questions> Questions, QuestionTypes Type)
 Question (string Description, List<Choice> Choices)
 Choice (string Description)
 enum QuestionTypes {MultipleChoicesOneAnswer, MultipleChoicesMultipleAnswers}
```

In a ListBox I want to display each question in its own border and the choices available for each question. Like so:
*1) How many hours are there in a day?

     [ ] 21

     [ ] 22

     [ ] 23

     [ ] 24*

The brackets above represent a radio button (if the question type is "MultipleChoicesOneAnswer") or a check box (for questions of type "MultipleChoicesMultipleAnswers")

I am using the following templates:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MultipleChoicesOneAnswerTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:Choice}">
   <RadioButton Content="{Binding Description}" Foreground="Blue"  />
</DataTemplate>


<DataTemplate x:Key="QuestionTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:Question}">
   <DockPanel>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding SortingIndex}" />
         <TextBlock Text=")" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
      </StackPanel>
      <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MultipleChoicesOneAnswerTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Choices}"/>
   </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

With these templates I get a RadioButton for each choice but they are not mutually exclusive per question.

**My questions to you are:**

1. What can I do to make the RadioButtons generated by the template be mutually exclusive?
 2. How would I go about recording to my model which choice the user chose?

Thanks a lot for your help.

**UPDATE:**
Following csunwold's suggestion it worked by using GroupName, but it feels a bit like a hack, since I had to override ToString() on the Question class spitting out the description and did GroupName="{Binding Question}".

Anybody else has a suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the radio buttons you want to be mutually excluse the same GroupName property.  You could probably record this to your model but creating one enum type that is updated each time one radiobutton is checked.

Comment: How can I get the GroupName from the DataTemplate? Thanks!

Comment: @Gustavo: Not sure if this will work, but you could try GroupName="{Binding Description}"

Comment: csunwold, Binding Description doesn't make sense, because each choice description are probably unique.
Using your idea I tried:
1) GroupName="{Binding Question, Path=Description}" (since Choice has a property pointing to the "master" Question). This did not work and I don't know why because it shows the question description correctly if I bind the RadioButton's content to it)
2) I overrode ToString on the Question class spitting out the description and did GroupName="{Binding Question}" and it worked. 

This really feels like a hack.

Comment: It may feel that way but the more I think about it it actually does make sense.  I have had to do quite a bit of overriding ToString when working with models like these.  I am starting to think that in as a general practice I should always override ToString when working with models like these, but I would be interested to hear the opinion of someone with more experience on this matter.  Glad to hear you got it working though.